# Swapping raster bands on disk efficiently using R

Tags: raster, r, sp

I have two raster files, each with RGB bands and an alpha layer. I would simply like to swap one of the raster's alpha bands for another, but to do so as efficiently as possible (these are very big files and there are a lot of them)

I started by trying this:

```
library(raster)    

ras1 <- brick("raster1.tif")
ras2 <- brick("raster2.tif")

ras1[[4]] <- ras2[[4]]

writeRaster(ras1, "newRaster.tif")
```

This, I believe, ends up rewriting the entire four layers, even if only one of the bands has changed.

I then thought I had found the perfect function with `raster::update`, but this turns out to be extremely slow

```
update(ras1, getValues(ras2[[4]]), 1, 4)
```

I am assuming it is because using `getValues` reads a bunch of data into memory. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe VRT files could work for your situation?

Comment: The low-level tools in rgdal possibly can do this, but not with raster. It's probably easier to write your own hooks into GDAL for this task, but maybe ImageMagick could do it. Definitely VRT will work, but you'd still be reading it all in to R to write out unless you use gdal_translate/gdalwapr on the VRT.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm not actually married to doing this in R. I'm not familiar with VRT. Could you give an example how this would look?

Comment: It would be easy enough to programmatically create the VRT against your file names, see the output of gdal_translate my.tif my.vrt -of VRT for one of your multi band files - you can probably chain gdal_translate .... myRGB.vrt -b 1 -b 2  -b 3   and gdal_translate ... myAlpha.vrt -b 4 and then gdalbuildvrt -separate myNew.vrt
 myRGB.vrt myAlpha.vrt  and then finally gdal_translate myNew.vrt myNew.tif - if they are all similar then template the .vrt without using the utilities is pretty straightforward